"Inconsistent Predictions in PyTorch Model: Single Image vs. Batch Processing"
I am noticing a significant difference in model predictions when running predictions on a single image versus the whole dataset. The model, which was trained using PyTorch, gives drastically different predictions for the same image when processed individually versus in a batch. Is there any way to ensure that the predictions are consistent for the same image when processed individually and in a batch?
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments, PreTrainedModel, PretrainedConfig
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

# Number of Features
num_of_features = 128

# Dataset Class
class SequenceDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.y = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.long)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {"input_ids": self.X[idx], "labels": self.y[idx]}


# Configuration Class
class SequenceConfig(PretrainedConfig):
    model_type = "sequence_transformer"

    def __init__(self, num_features=num_of_features, num_classes=3, d_model=1024, nhead=4, num_layers=4, dim_feedforward=512, **kwargs):
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.nhead = nhead
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.dim_feedforward = dim_feedforward
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


# Transformer Model
class SequenceTransformer(PreTrainedModel):
    config_class = SequenceConfig

    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.embedding = torch.nn.Linear(config.num_features, config.d_model)
        self.positional_encoding = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, config.d_model))
        encoder_layer = torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(
            d_model=config.d_model, 
            nhead=config.nhead, 
            dim_feedforward=config.dim_feedforward, 
            batch_first=True
        )
        self.transformer_encoder = torch.nn.TransformerEncoder(encoder_layer, num_layers=config.num_layers)
        self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(config.d_model, config.num_classes)

    def forward(self, input_ids, labels=None):
        src = self.embedding(input_ids) + self.positional_encoding
        output = self.transformer_encoder(src)
        logits = self.fc(output)
        probs = F.softmax(logits, dim=-1)

        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            loss_fct = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
            loss = loss_fct(logits, labels)
            
        return {"loss": loss, "logits": logits, "probs": probs} if labels is not None else logits


# Training Code
config = SequenceConfig()
model = SequenceTransformer(config)

# Training Arguments
    batchSize=32
    numWarmUpSteps=int(np.shape(train_image)[0]/batchSize/numOfBreakpointsPerEpoch/10)
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=path,
        num_train_epochs=1, 
        per_device_train_batch_size=batchSize,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=320,
        warmup_steps=numWarmUpSteps,
        weight_decay=0.1,
        logging_strategy='no',
        eval_strategy="epoch",
        save_strategy="epoch",
        metric_for_best_model="accuracy",
        save_only_model=True,
    )

# Trainer Initialization
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

# Train the Model
train_output = trainer.train()

# Save Model and Training Arguments
trainer.save_model("./SavedModels")
torch.save(training_args, "./SavedModels/training_args.bin")

# Prediction Code
training_args_loaded = torch.load("./SavedModels/training_args.bin")
model_save_path = "./SavedModels/"
model = SequenceTransformer(config).from_pretrained(model_save_path)

trainer = Trainer(model=model, compute_metrics=compute_metrics, args=training_args_loaded)
test_data = np.random.rand(10, num_of_features)  # Example test data
test_predictions = trainer.predict(torch.tensor(test_data, dtype=torch.float32))

# Output Test Predictions
print(test_predictions)

For single image its [0.37732467 0.2642143 0.35846105]
and for that same image in batch its [0.3185594 0.40971586 0.2717247 ].

Is the model in eval mode?

Thank you for your suggestion! I tried using .eval() and torch.no_grad(), but they don’t seem to make a difference.
It appears model.eval() is already invoked within .predict() in the Trainer class. Specifically, this line confirms it:
eval_loop = self.prediction_loop if self.args.use_legacy_prediction_loop else self.evaluation_loop
If you have other suggestions to ensure consistent predictions (single image vs. batches), I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

Try with eval mode.
I have added it and updated the code.
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments, PreTrainedModel, PretrainedConfig
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

# Number of Features
num_of_features = 128

# Dataset Class
class SequenceDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.y = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.long)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {"input_ids": self.X[idx], "labels": self.y[idx]}

# Configuration Class
class SequenceConfig(PretrainedConfig):
    model_type = "sequence_transformer"

    def __init__(self, num_features=num_of_features, num_classes=3, d_model=1024, nhead=4, 
                 num_layers=4, dim_feedforward=512, **kwargs):
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.nhead = nhead
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.dim_feedforward = dim_feedforward
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

# Transformer Model
class SequenceTransformer(PreTrainedModel):
    config_class = SequenceConfig

    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.embedding = torch.nn.Linear(config.num_features, config.d_model)
        self.positional_encoding = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, config.d_model))
        
        encoder_layer = torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(
            d_model=config.d_model, nhead=config.nhead, dim_feedforward=config.dim_feedforward, batch_first=True
        )
        self.transformer_encoder = torch.nn.TransformerEncoder(encoder_layer, num_layers=config.num_layers)
        self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(config.d_model, config.num_classes)

    def forward(self, input_ids, labels=None):
        src = self.embedding(input_ids) + self.positional_encoding
        output = self.transformer_encoder(src)
        logits = self.fc(output)
        probs = F.softmax(logits, dim=-1)
        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            loss_fct = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
            loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.config.num_classes), labels.view(-1))
        return {"loss": loss, "logits": logits, "probs": probs} if labels is not None else logits

# Assume `train_dataset`, `val_dataset`, `compute_metrics`, `path`, `train_image`, `numOfBreakpointsPerEpoch` are defined
# Training Code
config = SequenceConfig()
model = SequenceTransformer(config)

batchSize = 32
numWarmUpSteps = int(np.shape(train_image)[0] / batchSize / numOfBreakpointsPerEpoch / 10)
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=path,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batchSize,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=320,
    warmup_steps=numWarmUpSteps,
    weight_decay=0.1,
    logging_strategy='no',
    eval_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    metric_for_best_model="accuracy",
    save_only_model=True,
)

# Trainer Initialization
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

# Train the Model
train_output = trainer.train()

# Save Model and Training Arguments
trainer.save_model("./SavedModels")
torch.save(training_args, "./SavedModels/training_args.bin")

# Prediction Code
training_args_loaded = torch.load("./SavedModels/training_args.bin")
model_save_path = "./SavedModels/"
model = SequenceTransformer(config).from_pretrained(model_save_path)
model.eval()  # Ensure the model is in evaluation mode

trainer = Trainer(model=model, compute_metrics=compute_metrics, args=training_args_loaded)

test_data = np.random.rand(10, num_of_features)  # Example test data
test_data_torch = torch.tensor(test_data, dtype=torch.float32)

single_image = test_data_torch[0:1]
batch_images = test_data_torch

# Ensure no gradients are calculated during predictions
with torch.no_grad():
    # Process predictions for a single image
    single_prediction = trainer.predict(single_image)
    # Process predictions for a batch
    batch_predictions = trainer.predict(batch_images)

# Output Predictions
print("Single Prediction:", single_prediction.predictions[0])
print("Batch Prediction:", batch_predictions.predictions[0])

The reason for using eval:
while inference, batch normalisation layers apply the running estimates of mean and variance accumulated during training, ensuring that the input is Uniformly normalised, independent of the specific batch it's belong to.

Thank you for your suggestion! I tried using .eval() and torch.no_grad(), but they don’t seem to make a difference.
It appears model.eval() is already invoked within .predict() in the Trainer class. Specifically, this line confirms it:
eval_loop = self.prediction_loop if self.args.use_legacy_prediction_loop else self.evaluation_loop
If you have other suggestions to ensure consistent predictions (single image vs. batches), I'd appreciate it! Thanks!
